# Transfer function of two RC circuits connected together

Tags: circuit-analysis, transfer-function, laplace-transform

I need to find the transfer function of two RC circuits connected together.

This is the schematic:
[image: Circuit]

Here is how I tried solving it, using maple, the two equations for nodal tensions are found at **(1)** as the solve({**eq1**, **eq2**}) parameters:
[image: Solution attempt]

eq1 is the sum of currents at node A, eq2 is the sum of currents at node B.

Well my problem is that I get a result at **(3)** that is not the answer from the solutions booklet (which is at **(4)**).

I am quite rusty into solving circuits, could anyone take the time to explain me how to get to the correct answer? I must find the transfer function \$ G(s) = Y_{2}(s)/U_{1}(s) \$. \$ u_{1}(t) \$ is a voltage excitation, and \$ u_{2}(t) \$ is the same voltage as \$ V_{C_{1}}(t) \$.

Thanks!

P.S. If anyone could tell me what I did wrong in nodal analysis it would be great.

Comment: There is at least one mistake in first equation (node A). According to your sign conventions it should be \$(U-V_a)/R_1-...\$ and not \$V_a/R_1-...\$

Comment: @RespawnedFluff Circuit isn't exactly the same, there's no controlled source there, question differs.

Comment: @RogerC.Thanks for sharing, it indeed makes it "nearer" than the solution, but it still doesn't give the same equation as the solution. Not sure if I'm just too tired to see an obvious mistake...

Comment: What are your controlled sources? I don't see them in the circuit. While the other question may differ, the top-voted answer solves your problem too. Do you realize that if you eliminate "U" from your (5) you basically have the transfer function?

Comment: u2(t) is afaik a "controlled controlled" source as it has a gain of 1, voltage of 1 * Vc1. No I don't realize anything to be honest at this hour. All I wish is to find why I have failed at the nodal analysis. I could care less if there's another question out there that's similar to mine. The eq at (5) is the solution given to me, I wish to know *how* I can get to there, as explained already in my question.

Comment: Ok I'm dumb just realized I misread the schematic and regarded u2(t) as a controlled source, which is not. This answer should be trashed, I just realized +/- Va/R2 had not its place there. Sorry.